# How to detect shape in openCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I'd like to detect a custom shape using **a cameraStream + openCV**.

[image: img]

Now I'd like to detect the position of the shape in an real life image. Also I need to get some feature points of the shape displayed in this image:

[image: img2]

---

So I'm pretty sure **just detecting contours** will not make the full deal. Also **HoughTransform** will not be a really good method because tbh the contour could be more an crazy ellipse rather than a circle. Another disadvantage is that detecting the blue marked points will be nearly impossible.

---

I'm pretty sure I need to make use of **feature matching** or **keypoint detection** but tbh I do not really got any idea how to implement this feature in my camera stream nor how to detect the blue marked points as key points.

```
cv::Mat detectShape(cv::Mat defaultMat) {
    Mat rawMat = defaultMat;
    cvtColor(rawMat, rawMat, CV_BGR2RGB);

    Mat grayMat;
    rawMat.copyTo(grayMat);
    cvtColor(grayMat, grayMat, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    cv::Canny(grayMat, grayMat, 100, 200, 3);

    vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(grayMat, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    for (int i=0; i< contours.size(); i++) {
        vector<cv::Point> contour = contours[i];

        std::sort(contour.begin(), contour.end(), [](const cv::Point& a, const cv::Point& b) { return a.x < b.x; });
        cv::Point minX = contour[0];
        cv::circle(rawMat, minX, 5, Scalar(255, 0, 255), CV_FILLED);

        cv::Point maxX = contour.back();
        cv::circle(rawMat, maxX, 5, Scalar(255, 0, 0), CV_FILLED);

        std::sort(contour.begin(), contour.end(), [](const cv::Point& a, const cv::Point& b) { return a.y < b.y; });
        cv::Point minY = contour[0];
        cv::circle(rawMat, minY, 5, Scalar(0, 0, 255), CV_FILLED);

        cv::Point maxY = contour.back();
        cv::circle(rawMat, maxY, 5, Scalar(255, 255, 0), CV_FILLED);    
    }
    // how to apply feature detection?
    return rawMat;
}
```

**Note**: `detectShape` will be called for every frame of the camera stream and it's result will be displayed as camera frame.

Comment: Take a look to here: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html
and there:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d49/tutorial_moments.html

Comment: What is the shape your trying to detect? Are these images coming from an offline stream like a video? Or is this something like a live feed where you are tracking an object?

Comment: It is a life feed where I'd like to track the shape (object), yeah. @AdaRaider

Comment: I did take a look but tbh both of the refs you mentioned are not really helpful in my case. I know how to create a boundingRect or a enclosing circle. This is not what my question is about. Thanks anyways for your help @Jhon_Sharp1318.

Comment: Ok I might have some ideas I've had to track a paddle using two cameras and OpenCV before, I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: Can you modify this shape? Say for example, place markers on it? Is this an actual object you are looking at through the camera as it moves and that is why sometimes the perspective changes?

Comment: They are if you what you want is to describe shape... I mean the moments are just that

Comment: All right. I have already programmed a kind of 2d code (similar to a QR code) and the corresponding scanner. The scanner runs as iOSApp on the smartphone and is completely based on openCV combined with C++, objC & Swift. 

Now I want to develop another kind of 2d code, which has exactly this form (a kind of speech bubble). The shape of the code is round in its original state and has just this kind of triangle as a rotation marker, so that the scanner knows how the code is rotated. I can't use other markers, even if that would make the whole thing much easier. [...]

Comment: [...]  Nevertheless, it must also work without markers. The biggest problem is the perspective that turns a circle into an ellipse. **Edit**: `Is this an actual object you are looking at through the camera as it moves and that is why sometimes the perspective changes?` - (Exactly described, I couldn't have done it better.)

Comment: Ok, can you rely on the color of the bubbles?

Comment: @AdaRaider: No, the colours can be different. Especially as different colours can occur under different lighting conditions. So - you can't really count on colours (I speak from experience & many hours of wasted work). Probably the best option is a neural network - or like I've mentioned **key point matching** where I got absolutely no clue how to impelement this feature.

Comment: Given the parameters you've just described yeah this sounds like a job for AI, I'd agree with your assessment about a neural network. Unfortunately something I don't have much experience with. Good luck!

Comment: Neural network may be too slow to go along side your video frames. In feature keypoints  detection, go for SIFT(better accuracy) or SURF(faster); detection of keypoints for blurry images can be hard however.